# Connecting to an Oracle installation created by a third-party app

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

So I'm developing an application that is designed as a 'helper' application to a third-party application. This third-party application installs a 32-bit Oracle client.

I need my app to connect to this Oracle client. I'm writing it in C#; the third-party application is in Delphi.

So far I've managed to make it work by including Oracle DLL files in the same directory of my application - however this seems to be causing problems when I then go to run the third-party application (one of the functions of my app).

What would be the best way to locate and connect to an existing Oracle installation that I didn't create?

Thanks.

Comment: Might be a confusion or terms but The Delphi app talks to Oracle, in order to do that it needs the oracle Client stuff, so unless you are doing something eally weird I woudl have expected you to just use the built in OLeConnection, oleCommand stuff to connect to teh same Oracle database as the delphi app.

Comment: Why don't you just run the 32-bit Oracle Client installer when your program is installed?

Comment: Good point. Problem is I was hoping to make it portable so I can carry it from site to site.

Comment: Tony - I will look into using OLEConnection. I'm currently using using Oracle.DataAccess.Client